# How to determine timezone from changeset created_at data in OSM?

Tags: metadata, openstreetmap

this may be a stupid question, but I can't see which timezone the changeset was created in. Is all all the time converted to UTC?

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps in OSM changesets are stored in UTC. This can be deduced from the suffix `Z` at the end of the timestamp.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time:

> The time zone using UTC is sometimes denoted UTC±00:00 or by the
> letter Z—a reference to the equivalent nautical time zone (GMT), which
> has been denoted by a Z since about 1950. Time zones were identified
> by successive letters of the alphabet and the Greenwich time zone was
> marked by a Z as it was the point of origin. The letter also refers to
> the "zone description" of zero hours, which has been used since 1920.
> Since the NATO phonetic alphabet word for Z
> is "Zulu", UTC is sometimes known as "Zulu time".